# First error: SendEmail failed. First exception on row 0; first error: REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, Email body is required.: []

Tags: apex, batch

Although I've defined setPlainTextBody, it throws the error: First error: SendEmail failed. First exception on row 0; first error: REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, Email body is required.: []

global class OppStatusNotification_Batch implements Database.Batchable{

```
global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC)
{

    String query = 'Select Id, Name, StageName, Owner.Email from Opportunity';
    return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
}
global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Opportunity> scope)
{

    String messageBody;
    for(Opportunity opp : (List<Opportunity>)scope){
        if(opp.StageName == 'Submitted to Manager'){
            messageBody = 'This application was submitted to Manager.';
        }

        else if(opp.StageName == 'Declined by Manager'){
            messageBody = 'This application was declined by Manager'.;

        }

        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        String[] toAddresses = new String[] {opp.Owner.Email};
        email.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
        email.setSubject('Opportunity Name: ' + opp.Name);
        email.setPlainTextBody(messageBody);
        Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {email});
    }
}

global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC)
{

}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the stage is not either "Submitted to Manager" or "Declined by Manager", then `messageBody` will be null, thus producing this error. Consider filtering your batch process to filter opportunities by only one of those two stages.

Comment: actually there are 5 more values for which the email has to be sent. Would it be okay to filter opportunities with those values ?

Comment: @ngc Yes, just make sure that you're not processing records that will not be used.